# rational functions on affine line

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Take $\mathbb{C}$ as an affine variety. The ring of regular function is $\mathbb{C}[s]$. Now, I want to know the ring of rational functions. Is it $\mathbb{C}((s))=\mathbb{C}[[s]][s^{-1}]$?

Is true that in a neighborhood of a point every rational function could be seen as a power series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: No. The ring of rational functions is $\Bbb C(s)$. For an affine variety, the ring of rational functions is the field of fractions of the coordinate algebra.

2: Yes. Any rational function is analytic where it is defined. (This is essentially the quotient rule.)

Comment: For $\mathbb{C}(s)$ I mean $\mathbb{C}[s,s^{-1}]$ and this is not a field. Is there a description in terms of other rings of $\mathbb{C}(s)$? Thank you

Comment: That statement is **wrong**. $\Bbb C(s)$ is defined to be the fraction field of $\Bbb C[s]$, so it's $\{p/q\mid p,q\in\Bbb C[s], q\neq 0\}$ as a set.